# Cryptostrem to byte[] array

Tags: c#, encryption

What i would like to do is decrypt a file and save the Hex to a array. Problem im currently having is when i do extract it its in decimal representation of the hex value which i cannot convert back

code:

```
    int bits;
    DecryptFile
    (Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + 
     @"\Akd3\CFS.exe");
    }
    private void DecryptFile(string input)
    {
        string password = @"treeessss";
        byte[] Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);

        RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();

        FileStream FCrypted = new FileStream(input, FileMode.Open);
CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(FCrypted, 
AES.CreateDecryptor(Key, Key), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        int data;
        while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
        if((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
        {
            bits = bits + data;
        }
```

any ideas on how to extract the bytes or convert the decimal representation would be very helpful thank you

Comment: Thats not a complete snippet which doesnt help much.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]; maybe even visit the [help]

Comment: that is the whole snippet I dont know how where to go from there.  but because i cant save the cryptostream as bytes i decided to write it to int and use int bits = bits  + data; for conversion but in the end i couldnt convert it

Comment: as a side note i tried byte[] bytes;        and set it using bytes = bytes + Convert.ToByte but according to visual studios cant change byte to byte[]  so now im very confused on its not byte but i cant convert to byte

Comment: You should feed the `CryptoStream` into a `MemoryStream` and then call `ToByteArray` on the memory stream.

Comment: could you  go into a little more detail on how exactly? thanks

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `byte[]` from a `CryptoStream` using the following code:

```
byte[] result;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        cs.Write(inputData, 0, inputData.Length);
    }
    result = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Obviously the `cs.Write...` line can be replaced with a call to another stream to copy into `cs`